# How to differentiate meanings of "awesome"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I often use the literal ("old?") meaning of "awesome" in an equivocation:

> I smell awesome right now.

Then they say:

> No, you smell terrible.

And the punchline comes:

> I'm using the *awe-inspiring* definition of the word. My hot water heater has been broken for 3 days.

Is there something more clear than "awe-inspiring" which can be used here?

Comment: Maybe *I mean awesome in the literal sense of the word. My hot water heater has been broken for 3 days.*

Comment: This is a terrible pun. And not like a good terrible pun is. It's just bad.

Comment: I think you're conflating ***awesome*** and ***awful***. The best way to to improve the delivery of your jokes might be to *learn English*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He's actually not conflating them, in their most literal senses they are interchangeable and the joke (weak pun) he's making could easily have been used in an American joke book within a century. It's not a failure to "learn English" it's a mistake easily made by not realizing a difference between "dictionary English" and "modern colloquial English".

Comment: This is unrelated to awful. I am using the first definition in every dictionary I have consulted: huge, inspiring fear, inspiring awe.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a pretty lame joke, regardless.

Comment: I don't get this at all. What do you mean by 'cosmic'? That is entirely unclear. If you're using it metaphorically, what are the nuances you expect it to have?

Comment: @Mitch Thank you, I have reworded entirely. Hopefully this will now make the question valid.

Comment: Sounds very clear now. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

So I (and maybe some others assumed) that you weren't a native speaker when I saw this. Because frankly the correlation between awful and awesome is something that only lives on dictionaries and word nerds (no shame, fly that nerd flag!). Basically even when you "get it" it's not really funny :-) and modern English simply speakers aren't going to get it, and etymology supports that.
[Awesome has 1 consistent *assumed meaning* since at least the 1980's.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=awesome&allowed_in_frame=0)

If you personally really find it funny, you need to change the whole approach and payoff.

Since people already don't understand the "cosmic sense" of the two words, don't bother pointing it out. Find a way to make the pun explain itself.

2 potential puns:

The "phonetic pun"

"This post is AWESOME! I read it and thought 'awwwww some word nerd thinks he's funny.'" Exaggerate the faux sympathy by drawing out the awwwww sound.

The "semantic pun"

"X is/looks/tastes AWFUL!"
 "What are you talking about???"
"I just tried/saw/tasted X and am FULL of AWE baby!"

Individual humor is... individual.
But a joke that requires a dictionary to explain is never funny.

Comment: *Something that only lives on dictionaries?* It's true that the full (subscription-only) OED has the definition *Inspiring awe; appalling, dreadful, weird* for ***awesome*** (last citation 1870). But it's not in the online offerings from [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/awesome), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awesome), or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awesome). So I suggest OP didn't get this "contrived" meaning from a dictionary - it's just a careless assumption from a non-native speaker.

Comment: ... I have no explanation for why you find it hard to find.
https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aawesome
last synonym = (archaic) awful

Plus check his profile, he's from Philly. Hipster English-major is a safer bet.

Comment: It wasn't hard for *me* to find the archaic definition, since I have access to the full OED. I was just pointing out that it's not in what I'd regard as the three most "authoritative" online dictionaries (because it was never common even 200-300 years ago).

Comment: I'd give this answer +2 if I could.  I have people in my life that insist on trying to tell a joke from their native country translated (literally) into English.  Humor is SO about the usage of words and the shared understanding of both the actual meaning and the intended (funny) meaning that jokes and puns just aren't translatable.  Those of us who have tried to deliver a "bad" joke or pun get to recognize the blank look followed by an obligatory half "heh-heh" smile.  It's enough to make you go back to your day job! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I know exactly what you mean! My uncle taught me a pair of hilarious jokes in Russian... they're actually even not bad if the setup is translated, but the punchline HAS to be told in Russian.

Comment: I am a native English speaker. In the past 15 years in the US, *awesome* has become a popular word with the informal meaning "really great". When I use the definition listed first in every dictionary I have seen, it leads to downvotes. Do groupthink and colloquial usage hold more authority than published dictionaries?

Comment: @FullDecent A universal human truth is: everyone loves their own opinion best. This just happens to be Fumble's day to discover that an opinion he's taken for granted is factually inaccurate. It also happens to be a day that you discover that your opinion is unpopular, even though it has facts and centuries of usage on its side. Life is Awesome.
But yeah on a larger scale... this IS the internet, groupthink rules (and every group has it's own webpage).

Comment: @FullDecent oh yeah... for curiosity's sake (since you confirmed yourself as a native speaker) how close am I with the "Hipster English Major" guess? :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers all three of the online references you provide have their first definition relating to the "awe" version.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler not an English major. But for purposes of this discussion, you may classify me as an XKCD reader :-)

Comment: @FullDecent Bear in mind that dictionaries have differing policies about how glosses are ordered under headwords. The OED, for example, often cited as the "definitive" English dictionary, lists glosses in chronological order of appearance. Thus the first meaning it provides for many words is *not* the most common or best-understood; to the contrary, the oldest definition is often archaic or even obsolete. And bear in mind that yes, words mean what most people think they mean, regardless of what is recorded in the dictionary or not. Dictionaries are descriptive, not prescriptive. And often lag.

Comment: @DanBron thanks for the explanation. I am not trying to fight anybody here, just want to have fun and learn more about words.

Comment: @Full Decent: The definition that *doesn't* appear in those online dictionaries is *appalling, dreadful, weird*. Note that the original sense of *awe* is *Immediate and active fear; terror, dread*, which is flagged by OED as "obsolete". The normal current sense is their definition *The feeling of **solemn and reverential wonder,** tinged with latent fear, inspired by what is terribly sublime and majestic in nature, e.g. thunder, a storm at sea.*

Comment: HAHAHAHA welcome to two days ago!!!
no one ever argues like two people who are saying ALMOST EXACTLY the same thing...
Just let this one die.